# How to merge multiple CSS rules from duplicated selectors?

Tags: css

#### Precursor:

> Under normal circumstances, I would never do this.

I have a CSS file that I am currently collaborating on with another person. I built the file initially, then they have added rules to it after the fact. But, instead of adding rules to selectors that already exist, they have duplicated selectors everywhere. I don't even want to get into how disorganized the file has become. The problem is that the duplicated selectors are spread out all over the file now and it could take some time to sort it out.

Anyway, I am currently in the process of trying to clean up the file. I have tried beautify, css format, etc in my editor (ST3), which cleans up fine but still leaves the duplicate selectors. I have tried various online tools like [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/), [ProCSSor](http://tools.maxcdn.com/procssor/), [Dirty Markup](http://www.dirtymarkup.com/), [CleanCSS](http://www.cleancss.com/) and so far none of these tools give me the desired result.

**Is there any way that these selectors can be merged by some other means instead of manually?**

Here's an example of my situation, just for reference:

*I'd like to turn this...*

```
.sameClass {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.differentClass {
  border: none;
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
}

.sameClass {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

*into this...*

```
.sameClass {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.differentClass {
  border: none;
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is recommending to find a tool and is off topic for SO.

Comment: This has been working for me: [link](http://www.codebeautifier.com/)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith it is requesting a simpler way of merging duplicates other than manually on a very large file, anything... tool, voodoo, magic, command line, whatever works. Also, how is it off-topic when it's requesting alternate routes for a means to an end regarding fixing a coding issue?

I've modified the question in bold as to not use the actual verbiage "tool".

Comment: @pol thanks for taking the time to help and post a working resource. This actually does work well.

Comment: However you slice it, it will still be off topic for SO. You can see how to write a good question here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I was actualy just trying to help out, this is quoted from the link provided **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."**

Comment: For instance, if you turn this into a javascript or Jquery question, these two languages could do what it is you are asking for, however you will need to attempt it yourself first and when you get stuck, come back and ask the question. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith This Q&A is very helpful to me. Maybe it's better not considering finding a tool(what is tool) not so strict because a script, a class or an online service may be considered as a tool. I guess advice was just not asking an executable application to keep SO clear. And not all of us are perfect questioners. I generally think "Is this question scope off topic", if so I react.

Answer (score 7):

CSSO (Github project) is the tool will help you merge identical CSS classes.
It can be configured to execute some cleaning, compaction and restructuring.

Test in sandbox here : https://css.github.io/csso/csso.html

```
// Input
.card {box-shadow: none;}
.foo { color: #ff0000; }
.bar { color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); }
.card {border: 1px solid grey;}

// Output compacted + merged
.bar,.foo{color:red}
.card {box-shadow: none;border: 1px solid grey;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach would be to sort your CSS file(s) by selector. This can be done by considering each rule as a "paragraph" (meaning you will have to ensure there are empty lines between rules, and nowhere else), and then using your editor's "sort paragraph" feature, if it has one. For instance, emacs has the `M-x sort-paragraphs` command.

Once multiple rules for the same selector are grouped together, you can manually go in and combine them.